# Unable to add same view to Layout

Tags: android, layout, view

I have the following code to add a few views into a `LinearLayout` programatically. However strangely only 1 view is added successfully.

Thanks.

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.line, container, false);

    LinearLayout view1 = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.bg);

    view1.addView(new DrawView(x),1);
    DrawView k = new DrawView(x);
    k.setWidth();            
    view1.addView(k, 0);

    return rootView;
```

Updated with the xml layout file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bg"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Updated with view code

```
class DrawView extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();

public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);     
}

void setWidth(){
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
}
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 20, 20, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(20, 0, 0, 20, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(10, 10, 20, 20, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(0,50, 20, 20, paint);                        
}
```

Comment: Can you post the xml code for your LinearLayout please.

Comment: Check for supplying layout params while adding views...if the first view occupies full width and height,then the views added afterwards will become invisible.

Comment: updated my question with the layout file

Answer (score 0):

You need to add LayoutParams to your Views to define their sizing.

Comment: hi my view is in the form of a class instead of xml

Comment: Right, but you haven't internally defined the sizing in the class.  If you add LayoutParams to match the width and height of the lines you're drawing on the Canvas your box should show up.